# Why email from my server is being marked as spam by popular clients?

Tags: email, spam, email-spam, spamassassin

I am sending single letters of notifications, yet they are being marked as spam by almost every server.

I've got detailed report from "is not spam" service, but can't really understand what lines of it are important. From what I have gathered by googling, everything looks moderately OK, yet emails end up in spam anyway.

Please tell me, what am I missing.

http://isnotspam.com/dreport.php?id=42159&email=gouf@4otaku.ru

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To send email and have it not marked as spam you need to ensure a few different things.

1. Setup [SPF (Sender Policy Framework)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and ensure you are sending mail from the server you have specified in it.
2. Setup [DKIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) (Domain Keys Identified Email)
3. Ensure the server you are sending email from hasn't been blacklisted by any spam services (looks like it hasnt by that site you've linked to)

With all of this your messages can still be marked as spam if the content of them looks suspicous.

Amazon has a service [SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) that I have been using for sending emails, they make it really easy to setup most of this stuff and so far I haven't had any emails sent via that marked as spam.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just like to weigh in and say that some systems automatically score anything from the .ru TLD. It's among the list of the most frequently-abused TLDs by spammers. If you're sending the notifications with a subject like "Your Notification" or you are sending them unsolicited, you're very likely to get flagged.